# Crawl and extract multiple elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I try to crawl information from a certain website to get data of several names from YouTube-Channels, their belonging country and their URLs. Right now it is possible to crawl information of the channel name and url. My goal is to extract the country of the certain YouTube Channel, however sometimes it is possible that this information is missing. Right now I am able to extract the URL of each channel and the channel name, but I have no idea how to extract the title of the headline such as: ***title="Romania"***. I tried to use regular expression, but the problem is that the ***title*** contains sometimes two times in the header. The following code demonstrates my current procedure:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

for i in range(1, 300):
    url = "https://www.channelcrawler.com/eng/results/136630/page:%s" % i
    req = requests.get(url)
    data = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('h4'):
        #for t in link.find_all('title'):
        print(link)
        row = str(link)
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', row)
        print(urls)
        #print(link.text.strip())
        print(link.get_text())

Output:
<h4>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWmSq95JfUZTv1-Jxmkk-Rw" target="_blank" title="Ford South Africa">Ford South Africa</a> </h4>
['http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWmSq95JfUZTv1-Jxmkk-Rw']
...
<h4>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyfWjPOye4zFvEC_MkbJZ4w" target="_blank" title="Nutz Rider">Nutz Rider</a> <img alt="" src="/img/flags/gif/ro.gif" title="Romania"/> </h4>
['http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyfWjPOye4zFvEC_MkbJZ4w']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

    for i in range(1, 300):
        url = "https://www.channelcrawler.com/eng/results/136630/page:%s" % i
        req = requests.get(url)
        data = req.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

        for link in soup.find_all('h4'):
            a = link.find('a')
            print(a['href'])
            print(a['title'])
            print(a.text)
            a = link.find('img')
            print(a['title'])
        break
```

you can put the country in the square bracket and put the stuff in try catch..Hope this helps

Note: inserted break for testing

Comment: Hey I tried your code, but it only outputs the name of the channel twice instead of the country. As I explained the problem is that there is no specific variable for country. The name of the country is stored as well as the name of the channel in *title*

Comment: @Daniel hey thats not country name, i checked on youtube, that is there channel name, they chose it that way

Comment: If you look at my Output you can see that also the country is tracked *title="Romania"*

Comment: @Daniel hey i updated the code, now for country I am checking the images, since the image is their country flag  and we can get the country name from the title of the image